# Ubuntu Can't Run Speed Test

Tags: networking, 17.10, download-speed

I have a very weird problem. My internet appears to be working just fine, I can access web pages and ping Google.com (14ms), but I can't run speed tests. I was wondering about speed, so I googled speed test and ran it, but it wouldn't start (stuck on "Contacting Server"). I went to speedtest.net, with the same result. `speedtest-cli` told me it worked, but gave this output

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Comcast Cable (MY_IP)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Comcast (San Francisco, CA) [29.68 km]: 2516.589 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 0.00 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed................................................................................................
Upload: 0.00 Mbit/s
```

Obviously I don't have 0 Mbit/s (I'm submitting this question off of the affected computer), and both google and speedtest.net work when I boot the same computer into windows 10([my Win10 results](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/6734720178)). I rebooted my machine, I even tried turning off UFW, but nothing works. I have no idea what to even try next. Thanks.

Comment: That's a weird issue. Have you tried fast.com ?

Comment: @vishnunarayanan that one does work. Is there any reason that would be true?

Comment: The problem may be on the speedtest.net side, and when they fix it everything will go back to normal. In this case, it doesn't matter what you try or not try.

Comment: Ok so I used a couple speed tests that looked... Off brand. However, they all worked, so I guess this is just a speedtest.net issue. Still doesn't explain it working in Win10 though.  Thanks guys!

Comment: @brndn2k try this one http://beta.speedtest.net/. If this works the issue might be due to Adobe Flash. Can't be sure though.

Comment: @vishnunarayanan that didn't work. I'd expect that the cli wouldn't require flash, and it wasn't working either. Thanks anyway!

Comment: ah just wanted to see if that worked. The latency showing speed-test cli is very high.  Maybe something related to picking the nearest server or so.

Comment: Please try: `./speedtest-cli --server 1783` and then try: `./speedtest-cli --server  5026` Any improvement in the latency?